# Issue with loading an PFImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, lazy-loading

I have a `PFQueryTableView` with PFImageViews. I'm trying to load the images lazily following this tutorial :http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/loading-remote-images-in-a-table-view/

This is my old code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let imageWillUse = object!["Image"] as! PFFile
    var imageToLoad = UIImage()
    do {
        try imageToLoad = UIImage(data:imageWillUse.getData())!

    } catch {

        print(error)
    }
    cell.postImageView.file = imageToLoad
```

now, following the tutorial, I changed to this code

```
let image: PFFile = object!["Image"] as! PFFile
cell.postImageView.file = image //error on this line
```

Xcode reports `[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` when I try to run it. What do I need to change?

Comment: Have you set the type of the object to be a `PFImageView` in your storyboard in the attributes inspector? Or if not using storyboard, make sure that the object declared in your cell's subclass is a `PFImageView` not a `UIImageView`

Comment: Thank you so much for reminding! I haven't set my image view in storyboard as a `PFImageView`. Now it works!